# What am I missing in this IsEmpty clause?

Tags: vba, excel

In an Excel VBA module I'm building, I have some code to execute if a table of out-of-gauge cargo contains anything. I initially wrote this:

```
If Not IsEmpty(Range("OOGData")) Then
...
Else
...
End If
```

But even when OOGData *is* empty, it keeps returning `False`. I've tried it with If IsEmpty(Range("OOGData")) = False Then` but that doesn't seem to make any difference. My current code is

```
If IsEmpty(Range("OOGData")) = False Then
```

...but that *still* activates with the empty range.

I've made sure there are no formulae, hidden values or anything that could be showing up.

Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Have you cleared the cells? That is, deleting the contents, I believe, doesn't empty the cell, rather, I think, it contains 0 length String. So the check might have to check for it either being empty or having a 0 length string (this is juts off my head, so it might not be completely correct). Here's some code that I have used `If IsNull(cv) Or IsEmpty(cv) Or cv = "" Then`

Answer (score 1):

According to [this information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264227.aspx):

> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether a variable has been
>   initialized.

In your code you are not working with variable therefore you shouldn't expect correct value.

When checking single cell you should use `Len()` function instead:

```
If Len(Range("OOGData"))=0 Then
    'cell is empty
```

When checking if range of cells is empty use this solution:

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("OOGData"))=0 Then
    'rabge is empty
```

The final alternative I can think of is to use loops.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to cheat. Instead of checking the list there, I've added a Boolean variable (`bContainsOOG`) that's set to **True** any time an OOG cargo item is added to the OOG list, and then the reporting sub checks against that instead. But thanks both of you for those suggestions, they'll come in handy in another bit I was getting stuck on. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a function that I thinks very closely fits:-

```
' Function to determine the last (first blank/null/empty) cell in a series of data in either a column
' or row
' Usage :- DataSeriesEnd(w,r,b)
'           where   w is the name of the worksheet.
'                   r is the row or column as an integer
'                   b is a boolean (true/false) if true then processing a column, if false a row
Public Function DataSeriesEnd(Worksheet As String, rc_index As Integer, bycolumn As Boolean) As Integer
    Dim cv As Variant

    For DataSeriesEnd = 1 To 500
        If bycolumn Then
            cv = Worksheets(Worksheet).Cells(DataSeriesEnd, rc_index)
        Else
            cv = Worksheets(Worksheet).Cells(rc_index, DataSeriesEnd)
        End If
        If IsNull(cv) Or IsEmpty(cv) Or cv = "" Then Exit For
    Next DataSeriesEnd

    ' Position to previous cell (i.e. this one is empty)
    DataSeriesEnd = DataSeriesEnd - 1

End Function
```

Note! There is a limit of 500 rows/columns